# Is this a good database design?

Tags: mysql

I am planning to make a railway reservation project...
I am maintaining following tables:

> **trainTable**
> (trainId,trainName,trainFrom,trainTo,trainDate,trainNoOfBoogies)...PK(trainId)
>
> **Boogie**
> (trainId,boogieId,boogieName,boogieNoOfseats)...CompositeKey(trainId,boogieId)...
>
> **Seats**
> (trainId,boogieId,seatId,seatStatus,seatType)...CompositeKey(trainId,boogieId,seatId)...
>
> **user**
> (userId,name...personal details)
>
> **userBooking**
> (userId,trainId,boogieId,seatId)...

Is this good design?

Answer (score 2):

It could work, but there is **room for improvement** - depends what you are using it for and how you want to optimize it:

- Be **consistent** in naming your tables. You shouldn't name one table `trainTable`, another `Boogie` and a third one `Seats`. Either always have the "*table*", or never; either always use plural, or never. Try `trains`, `boogies`, `seats`.
- You don't have to repeat the tablename in the columnname - when referring to `train.id`, it's clear enough. But this is up for discussion, some people do. But be **consistent**: also use `username` and not just `name`
- Do you need **an extra field** `traintable.trainNoOfBoogies`? You can get this information by just COUNTING all boogies with that given trainID.
- Same thing for seats: do you need a `Boogie.boogieNoOfSeats`? You can just SELECT COUNT(*) from seats where boogieID = wantedId`.
- The `seats` table is linked to a boogie AND to a train? You can probably just link a seat to a boogie. The boogie itself will link to a train. If you put the **link in more than once**, you risk inconsistencies (but then again, you'd have to post the specs for me to see what you want...)

Proposal:

```
trains
(ID,name,from,to,date) PK(ID)

boogies
(ID,trainId,name,) CompositeKey(trainId,boogieId)...

seats
(ID, trainID, boogieID, status, type ) CompositeKey(trainId,boogieId,seatId)

users
(ID, name, ... personal details) PK (ID) 

userBookings
(ID, userId, trainId, boogieId, seatId) CompositeKey(trainId,boogieId,seatId)
```

If you want more tips, post a bit more information: what do you want to store, what do you want to do with it? What are example queries programmers will write against the database?

Comment: but how can i implement it in MySQL & hibernate...
Please reply me

Comment: Sorry alokpatil, I'm familiar with MySQL, but not hibernate - you should post a new question with "How do I implement this database design in MySQL and Hibernate" -> that will attract experienced users to help you :)

Comment: Ok thanks, please give the scripts how to declare the following tables & their schemas...Once again I am asking the same question...Is it a good design to develop a industry level project...for showing our seniors to evaluate us...because we are freshers working in one company & our evaluation will be on this project, so I dont want to miss any chance to get the position in industry...

Comment: I found that by dropping plurals in my table names, it made eveything soo much easier to view, for example I much prefer having tables named as "Product, Booking, User" than "Products, Bookings, Users" - the singular form seems to read better for me.

Comment: @Dal: it's a matter of personal preference. In the MySQL information schema, they use "tables", "columns", "views" etc. It can also help to avoid reserved keywords (try having a table 'view' or 'table' - possible, but a lot of escaping and tools ill-parsing :))

Comment: @Konerak - Agreed, it appears to be preference, I guess I've become soo used to [escaping] everything in MSSQL it doesn't bother me anymore... more food for thought:

http://discuss.fogcreek.com/joelonsoftware/?cmd=show&ixPost=5904

Comment: Hehe, tl;dr, though I agree with the first line of first comment: "This is a religious issue, and I don't think it makes one tiny little bit of difference to anything." :)